# I'm getting EOF errors in a command I'm trying to make for fun. What's going on?

Tags: command-line, bash

So, I'm a pretty new user with Ubuntu 20.04, and I've been trying to figure out how to make my own commands. I've been trying to make a command with a series of if-then statements to figure out how they work, and I keep getting the same errors. Here's the code:

```
    echo "Would you like to see the secret? (Y/N)"
read AFFIRM
if [$AFFIRM == Y]; then
    echo "Alright, but first I need to ask a few questions. Ready? (Y/N)"
    read AFFIRM2
    if [$AFFIRM2 == Y]; then
        echo "Great. First, what is the name of this computer?"
        read COMNAME
        if [$COMNAME == thesynthetichuman -o $COMNAME == Computer X]; then
            echo "Correct! Next question: What was the name of the first user on this computer?
            read USERNAME
            if [$USERNAME == synthetichuman]; then
                echo "Correct again! Last question: What is your favorite color?"
                read FAVCOLOR
                echo $FAVCOLOR >> " eh? Nice. Here is the secret!
//ascii art
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII????????????IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII????++++++++++++++????IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?++++++??????????????++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+++???????????????????????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????????????????????????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????????????????????????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????????????????????????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++??????????????????????+++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+++++++????????????+++++++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII???++++++++++++++???IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++++++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+????????++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++++++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++++++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?I???III?????+++??????+++?????????????IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIII?++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIII??++??++????????????????????????++????????++??++??IIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIII+??????+???????????????????????+?++?????????+????+++IIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII?+++????+???????++++??++++????????+++????????+????+++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+++++???+???????++++++++++????????+++????????+??++??+?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+???+++++?????+++???++???+++????????+????????++++???+?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+?????+++???????+???++???+??????????+????????+++????+?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+++++???+????????+++??+++???????????+???????++???++++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+????+++++????????++++++????????+???+?++????+++++???++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+???????++??????????++??????????????+???????++??????++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+???????++++??????????????????????+++?????+++???????+?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII++++?????+??+?????????????????????+++???+++++?????+++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+?+++????+II?++++++???????????????+++++++?II+???++??++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+?????++++IIII++++++++++++++++++++++++IIIIII++??????++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII++??????++IIII+++?????????????++++++++IIIIII+?????+++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+++++????+IIII+++++++????????????????+IIIIII+???+++++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+???++???+IIII+++?++++++++++++++++++++IIIIII+?+++???++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII??????++++IIII++??????????++++++++++++IIII??++++?????IIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIII??I???++IIII++++???????????????????+IIII??++???IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?IIII++????????++++++++++++++IIIIII?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++????????????????????+IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++++++++??????????????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++?????+++++++++++++++++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
+?????????????????????????+++????????+++++++++??++???????????????????????????+++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                                                                 GlassGiant.com"

            else
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        else
            echo "Wrong!"
        fi
    

    elif [$AFFIRM == N]; then
        echo "Okay then. Bye!"

    else
        echo "Look, I had very specific instructions. Why did you ignore them? Y or N. That is it. Come on."
    fi

elif [$AFFIRM == N]; then
    echo "Okay then. Bye!"

else
    echo "Look, I had very specific instructions. Why did you ignore them? Y or N. That is it. Come on." // I seem to be getting "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'" errors on lines like this.

fi
echo "Bye!"
//syntax error: unexpected end of file???
```

I'm confused. The EOF error appears on seemingly random lines, and the syntax error appears no matter what. I don't understand how to fix the errors, and all of my googling so far has been in vain. Can someone help?

Comment: Just the syntax highlighting in the question shows the quoting is broken. Also run your code through shell

Comment: Install and use `shellcheck` or visit https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Instead if testing such big piece of code at once, test it part by part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

social distancing, i was bored...
there were syntax errors, missing quotes, logic errors.
you'll have to go line by line to see what I changed... I would always use quotes when referencing strings in the if statements.. in some cases you had to. Use comments when you have nested ifs... As turbulence mentioned.. test part by part when troubleshooting, I did, until it worked (i even learned about the if statement splitting the arguments)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Would you like to see the secret? (Y/N)"
read AFFIRM

if [ $AFFIRM == "Y" ]; then
    echo "Alright, but first I need to ask a few questions. Ready? (Y/N)"
    read AFFIRM2

    if [ $AFFIRM2 == "Y" ]; then
        echo "Great. First, what is the name of this computer?"
        read COMNAME
        if [ "$COMNAME" == "thesynthetichuman" -o "$COMNAME" == "Computer X" ]; then
            echo "Correct! Next question: What was the name of the first user on this computer?"
            read USERNAME
            if [ $USERNAME == "synthetichuman" ]; then
                echo "Correct again! Last question: What is your favorite color?"
                read FAVCOLOR            
                echo  $FAVCOLOR "eh? Nice. Here is the secret!


?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII????????????IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII????++++++++++++++????IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?++++++??????????????++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+++???????????????????????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????????????????????????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????????????????????????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++??????++??????????++??????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+??????????????????????????+?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++??????????????????????+++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?+++++++????????????+++++++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII???++++++++++++++???IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++++++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+????????++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++++++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++++++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?I???III?????+++??????+++?????????????IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIII?++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++?IIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIII??++??++????????????????????????++????????++??++??IIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIII+??????+???????????????????????+?++?????????+????+++IIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII?+++????+???????++++??++++????????+++????????+????+++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+++++???+???????++++++++++????????+++????????+??++??+?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+???+++++?????+++???++???+++????????+????????++++???+?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+?????+++???????+???++???+??????????+????????+++????+?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+++++???+????????+++??+++???????????+???????++???++++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+????+++++????????++++++????????+???+?++????+++++???++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+???????++??????????++??????????????+???????++??????++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+???????++++??????????????????????+++?????+++???????+?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII++++?????+??+?????????????????????+++???+++++?????+++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+?+++????+II?++++++???????????????+++++++?II+???++??++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+?????++++IIII++++++++++++++++++++++++IIIIII++??????++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII++??????++IIII+++?????????????++++++++IIIIII+?????+++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+++++????+IIII+++++++????????????????+IIIIII+???+++++?IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII+???++???+IIII+++?++++++++++++++++++++IIIIII+?+++???++IIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIII??????++++IIII++??????????++++++++++++IIII??++++?????IIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIII??I???++IIII++++???????????????????+IIII??++???IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII?IIII++????????++++++++++++++IIIIII?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++????????????????????+IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++++++++??????????????++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
?IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII++?????+++++++++++++++++IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII+++
+?????????????????????????+++????????+++++++++??++???????????????????????????+++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                                                              glassassnt.com"
                                                                                             
            else
                echo "Wrong!" #username
            fi
        else
            echo "Wrong!" #comname
        fi
    elif [ $AFFIRM2 == "N" ]; then
        echo "Okay then. Bye!" #affirm2

    else
        echo "Look, I had very specific instructions. Why did you ignore them? Y or N. That is it. Come on."
    fi

elif [ $AFFIRM == "N" ]; then
    echo "Okay then. Bye!" #affirm
else
    echo "Look, I had very specific instructions. Why did you ignore them? Y or N. That is it. Come on."
fi

echo "Bye!"
```

Comment: then using single brackets you need to quote variable names too

Comment: Thank you! I'm really new to this, so I was very confused. This is really helpful!